# Add to cart button showing for out of stock variable products in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I have a weird thing happening with my Woocommerce store.

Right now when a single product (no variants) is out of stock the 'Quantity' and 'Add to Cart' button disappear - which is what I want. It just shows the 'Out of Stock' label.

When I have a variable product (with say 2 variants) that has all variants out of stock, it's still showing the 'Quantity' and 'Add to Cart' buttons (grayed out).

How do I hide the Quantity + Add to Cart button in ALL cases regardless of whether it's a single or variable product when it is OUT OF STOCK?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin that will help you to hide the add to cart button particular to product : [Woocommerce Hide Add To Cart Button](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-add-to-cart-button/)

It helps to hide the add to cart button for ,

```
Hide Add to Cart button from product single page.
Hide Add to Cart button from category page.
Hide Add to Cart button from homepage and all other pages.
```

Also you can hide it via adding the below function in `functions.php`,

```
if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
        global $product;
        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;
        woocommerce_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: That ALWAYS hides the add to cart though.. I only want it hidden when the product is out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

can you post a link to the site or a dev site so we can have a look. Alternatively implement the following code.

```
.[class for for button if product is out of stock]{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide it with css! I'd like to hide that entire add to cart portion via php

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'get_selected_variation_stock' );
function get_selected_variation_stock() {
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type( 'variable' ))
    {
        $stockArr = array();
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach ($available_variations as $key => $value)
        {
            $variation_id = $value['variation_id'];
            $attribute_pa_colour = $value['attributes']['attribute_pa_colour'];
            $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
            $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

            $stockArr[] = [
                "id"  => $variation_id,
                "qty" => $stock
            ];

        }

        ?>

        
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                var arr =  echo json_encode($stockArr); //this value can be wrap up into php tag mostly. Otherwise functionality not works.

                jQuery('input.variation_id').change( function(){
                    if( '' != jQuery('input.variation_id').val() ) {

                        var var_id = jQuery('input.variation_id').val();

                        const objectArray = Object.entries(arr);
                        objectArray.forEach(([key, value]) => {

                            var prod_id  = value.id;
                            var prod_qty = value.qty;

                            if (prod_id == var_id) {

                                if (prod_qty > 0) {
                                    jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button").removeClass("disabledCartBtn");
                                    jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button").html("Add to cart");
                                    jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button").removeAttr("disabled");
                                }
                                else {
                                    jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button").addClass("disabledCartBtn");
                                    jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button").html("Out of stock");
                                    jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button.button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                                }

                            }

                        });

                    }
                });
            });
        
    <?php

}

}
```

Add this code into functions.php and you have to achieve your goal.